# What sans-serif typeface is used for this "lunch" logo?

Tags: font-identification, sans-serif

What font type is being used on the following page for "lunch", a logo for a Meatless theme?

[image]

http://themes.meatless.io/lunch/index.php

I've been trying to match it and haven't been able to find something similar.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm going to go with [Open Sans](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Open+Sans), since that's what Meatless is using for a lot of its text content:

[image: Open Sans screenshot]

That's the "Extra Bold 800" weight. Default kerning is looser than what your source has.